# How to keep a TCP Socket alive and detect a disconnect?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

In my C# program, I use TCP Sockets for communication. 
How does the Socket know, that there is no more connection, when the other side hasn't properly called Shutdown/Close or whatever. 
Like for example when Internet connection is lost. 
What I learned about TCP is that it sends keep alive packets. What are the standard values for this, how frequently are they send, where can I set the interval and how can I set the disconnect timeout ( the time to wait before the connection is considerd disconnected when nothing is received )?

Comment: TCP dos not send/recv keepalives by default, and loss of reachability cannot be detemined without attempting to exchange data with the peer.  If you are just waiting on a recv() call, you could wait forever.

Comment: Stephen Cleary has a amazing [article on Half-Open Sockets](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html). Honestly, the information contained within the faq on his blog is priceless for understanding TCP sockets as a whole. [Here is the overview for his FAQ](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) I would give those a solid reading.

Comment: This has been covered 100 times. I'm sure a search engine will answer all of this.

Comment: I have of course used a search engine, but with no satisfying results and couldn't find anything about the standard values. This for example only says something about using keep alives, but no further explanation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If a socket doesn't send or receive any data then by definition the socket is alive and open.  A TCP can sit forever and so long as each end knows about it's current state it will still work.

The issue you can run into is where intermediate device (such as stateful firewall) maintains a timeout for the TCP connection that has nothing to do with the end device and the the end devices have no visibility.  If after, two three or even four days, one devie wants to send data on the TCP channel, if an intermediate device fails to send it on, then and only then will the socket "disconnect".

In relation to your question about tcp-keep-alives - this is Operating System dependent.

Here's a good write up on the Windows way: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nettracer/2010/06/03/things-that-you-may-want-to-know-about-tcp-keepalives/